# Using parameter in function to call a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined a variables outside of a function and I need to be able to call the variable depending on the parameter that is called with the function.

**HTML**

```
<button id="Area300" style="left:755px;" onclick="a('normal', 'Area300')"></button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var Area300_Data = "somedata"
function a(data, data1) {
  if (data=='extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data=='normal') {
    console.log(data1+_Data)
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

How do I combine the parameter of `data1` to `_Data` to get (in this case) `Area300_Data`?

Comment: use `object` `key` `value` pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may not work unless you use `eval`.
Secondly `_Data` will act as a variable unless you add it as a string. So either put it inside  quotes or use template literals

```js
var Area300_Data = "somedata"

function a(data, data1) {
  if (data == 'extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data == 'normal') {
    console.log(eval(`${data1}_Data`))
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="Area300" style="left:755px;" onclick="a('normal', 'Area300')" type='button'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need `eval` here. `var` variables are stored into the `window` object. Except if the code is already into a function context, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I have `var Area300_Date` defined in a window.onload function (as the data for the variable is from a JSON file). I get the error `Area300_Data is not defined at eval` How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the global scope, every `var` are stored into `window`

So you can

```
window[`${data1}_Data`]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the data in Object and access that data like property

e.g

```
var data = {
 Area300_Data : "somedata"
}
```

Now you can access that data dynamically like this

```
function a(data, data1) {
  if (data=='extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data=='normal') {
    console.log(data[data1+'_Data'])
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

It will be more readable than accessing window object

Answer (score 0):

`data1+_Data` apply `+` operator between two variables named `data1` and `_Data`. You can't access the variable like.
 In this case `Area300_Data` is in global scope and declared using `var` so its present in `window`. You you access it from `window` using Bracket Notation `[]`

```js
var Area300_Data = "somedata"
function a(data, data1) {
  if (data=='extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data=='normal') {
    console.log(window[`${data1}_Data`])
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="Area300" style="left:755px;" onclick="a('normal', 'Area300')">button</button>
```

However I would prefer to keep the data in and object named `Data` and access it from there

```js
let Data = {
   Area300:"somedata"
}
var Area300_Data = "somedata"
function a(data, data1) {
  if (data=='extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data=='normal') {
    console.log(Data[data1])
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="Area300" style="left:755px;" onclick="a('normal', 'Area300')">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to create an object which uses data1 as a key may be something like that?

```
var gobalInfo = {
   Area300: "somedata"
}
function a(data, data1) {
  if (data=='extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data=='normal') {
    console.log(globalInfo[data1]);
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `eval` to get variable data. for example

```js
var Area300_Data = "300 Area Data";
var Area600_Data = "600 Area Data";

function a(data, data1) {
  if (data == 'extra') {
    //do something
  } else if (data == 'normal') {
    console.log(eval(`${data1}_Data`))
    //Should display "somedata"
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="a('normal','Area300')">Click to see Area300</button>
<button onclick="a('normal','Area600')">Click to see Area600</button>
```